# How to configure apache Flink with Apache atlas for lineage?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-atlas

I am looking for integrating Apache Atlas with Apache Flink to capture Job lineage. I found some references around it from Cloudera (CDP) and they are using Atlas-flink hook , But not able to find any documentation or implementation without CDP and Atlas-Flink connection JAR as well.
Let me know if anyone has done integration between them?

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6757 for a bit of info.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson, I went through it, Looks like only Cloudera (CDP) having implementation in place. Still opensource version not having this capability.